# Como verificar o que uma página html/javascript está carregando?

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-chrome, firefox

Como posso verificar o que meu navegador está tentando carregar, mesmo após a página html/javascript já ter carregado "completamente"?

A página é: http://cerva.tk/index.html

Se puderem façam um teste e verão que ele entrega o resultado corretamente, mas o browser fica carregando algo... não sei exatamente o que...

Além disso, ao menos, no Chrome e Android o resultado não é exibido... ou é exibido e já volta para página inicial não deixando o usuário ver o resultado.
Suspeito que esse "codigo" que ele fica carregando no browser seja responsável por esse problema no Android.

Comment: nem no desktop dá pra ver o resultado.

Comment: Acessando direto pelo http://www.timeu.com.br/cerva/?Litrão=&600+ML=&Long+Neck=&Litrinho=&Lata+350ml=&Latão+473ml= ainda dá mais tempo de ver piscando o resultado.

Comment: ué... aqui tá funcionando perfeitamente em ambos os links...

http://imgur.com/RICtEki

Comment: Acho que vc tem que testar em vários browsers pra ter uma idéia melhor.

Comment: o esquisito é que testei em no Firefox e Chrome em 3 micros diferentes com versões diferentes de S.O. (Ubuntu 15.10, Ubuntu 15.04 e Windows 10) e todos funcionaram perfeitamente normal... exceto pelo loading eterno do browser depois de mostrar o resultado...

Comment: Aqui ele mal aparece e já volta pro form no **Opera 35** - No **IE11** ele para no resultado - No **Vivaldi** ele volta pro form, nao dá tempo de ler - No **Iron**, mesmo problema, nao dá tempo de ler. - No **Firefox** ele fica "carregando", mas aparenta ser justamente o que dá o retorno nos outros.

Answer (score 1):

Para verificação passo a passo no navegador, você poderá fazer utilizar o próprio depurador do navegador (f12). Onde clicando no botão de pause você consegue ver passo a passo o que ocorre.

Utilizando o depurador de scripts:
[image: Depurador de script]

Verificando a Rede (GET e POST)

[image: GET e POST]

Mas de certo modo o site está funcionando bem.

Comment: de 5 browsers que eu testei até agora, só em 2 funciona. nao diria que isso é "funcionando bem".

Comment: Já deu Ctrl + F5 nos browsers?

Comment: Se eu der control + f5 e resolver o problema, fica fácil. Basta ele colocar uma mensagem na entrada do site "Caro usuário, se este é seu primeiro acesso, favor dar um control + f5 antes de usar o site".

Comment: PS: O comentário anterior foi só pra por em perspectiva o teste que eu fiz em condições reais, que seria o mesmo que um usuário novo acabando de entrar no site. Que fique claro que não estou desprezando o questionamento dado, apenas acho perigoso esse tipo de teste por justamente esconder o problema, em vez de resolver. Para fins de desenvolvimento, o control + f5 pode realmente ajudar o autor a testar com a versão mais recente das modificações. Importante inclusive, usar um browser configurado para não salvar nada depois de fechada a sessão corrente (nem cookies, nem storage)

Comment: Não disse no intuito de "esconder" o problema, foi no intuito mesmo de ter a certeza que o seu navegador não está utilizando situações guardadas anteriormente (Que os usuários nos comentários disseram que estava funcionando normalmente). Meu objetivo é ajudar a resolver o problema e não esconder algo que pode ser uma possível dor de cabeça futuramente. Estou apenas descartando as coisas mais bobas até as mais complexas...

Comment: Tenho certeza que o comentário foi pra ajudar, obviamente. Mas entendeu também o que eu disse sobre esconder sem querer né? A possibilidade de funcionar só na segunda vez pode ser confundida com o problema ter sido resolvido. O teste do F5 é bom, mas só se depois o desenvolvedor limpar e fechar tudo, e o site funcionar na 1a vez também. Quanto à sua resposta, eu acho que o que está indicando como caminho pra solução está correto, mas a afirmação do final atrapalha um pouco.

Comment: usando o depurador... aparentemente não encontrei nada de errado...

Comment: A pergunta é interessante, assim como o domínio grátis TK informado na imagem.